# How to add new configuration file into Linux kernel

Tags: linux

I am working on Linux kernel, I want to create own configuration file for my board. Similar to x86-64_defconfig and i386_defconfig. I tried changing in arch/x86/Makefile.I doubt changing here will not suffice. What are the other files i need to change to add new configuration file.
or just copying my file into arch/x86/configs is enough ??

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Consider `make menuconfig`

Comment: Hi Basile Starynkevitch, i created my board specific config file and copied this into arch/x86/configs/ is this enough for adding new config file to linux kernel.